# Django: updated_at/created_at fields have TZ info are "too" precise

Tags: python, django-models

My env: Django 1.9.7, Python 3.5.2

I use the following model code to enforce values into `updated_at` and `created_at` fields in my model class.

```
class MyObject(models.Model):
   ...
   ...
   ...
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
   updated_at = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, auto_now=True)
```

When creating new model objects this fields in my database look like this:

```
|          created_at           |          updated_at           |
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| 2016-08-20 15:21:34.959854-04 | 2016-08-20 15:21:34.959924-04 |
| 2016-08-20 15:21:34.977791-04 | 2016-08-20 15:21:34.97785-04  |
| 2016-08-20 15:21:34.979975-04 | 2016-08-20 15:21:34.980013-04 |
| 2016-08-20 15:21:34.981981-04 | 2016-08-20 15:21:34.982019-04 |
| 2016-08-20 15:21:34.983878-04 | 2016-08-20 15:21:34.983917-04 |
| 2016-08-20 15:21:34.985832-04 | 2016-08-20 15:21:34.98587-04  |
| 2016-08-20 15:21:34.987758-04 | 2016-08-20 15:21:34.987796-04 |
| 2016-08-20 15:21:34.989791-04 | 2016-08-20 15:21:34.989855-04 |
```

It's great to know I can measure things up to the microsecond but Ideally I would like to have those fields accurate up to the second. I don't really need more than that and I don't need to TZ in there.

```
|          created_at           |          updated_at           |
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| 2016-08-20 15:21:34           | 2016-08-20 15:21:34           |
| 2016-08-20 15:21:34           | 2016-08-20 15:21:34           |
| 2016-08-20 15:21:34           | 2016-08-20 15:21:34           |
```

In my project's `settings.py` I have this defined:

```
USE_TZ = False
```

and yet the time zone still appears in the database.

My questions are:

1. How can I make sure I have a YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS output in my `updated_at` and `created_at` fields
2. If removing the microseconds isn't possible - how do I remove the TZ only from the timestamp?
3. If I do manage to do it -- Will there be any negative implications for not having the full timestamp in there? I.e. comparison functions already existing in Python that expect it etc.

Comment: I am more curious about why you want to remove the microsecond bit? Is it about displaying it? Maybe if you mentioned why you want to remove it you could get an alternative answer on how else to deal with the problem

Comment: Just for the sake of knowing how to customize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your own default value (script below), but with `auto_now` you cannot do anything, because implementation doesn't offer more.

```
import datetime


def default_datetime():    
    now = datetime.datetime.now()   
    now.replace(microsecond=0)      
    return now


class MyObject(models.Model):   
    ...
    ...
    ...
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, default=default_datetime)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, null=False)


my_object = MyObject(
    ...,
    updated_at=default_datetime     
)
```

From Django Note:

> The auto_now and auto_now_add options will always use the date in the default timezone at the moment of creation or update. If you need something different, you may want to consider simply using your own callable default or overriding save() instead of using auto_now or auto_now_add; or using a DateTimeField instead of a DateField and deciding how to handle the conversion from datetime to date at display time.

Comment: so I can assume I can use the same technique to remove the timezone

Comment: Yes. Anyway my answer answers to your first and second question. About question number 3, to not have negative implications, you have to use everywhere naive datetime, so the same that function default_datetime returns. If you'll have more questions, then just ask.